# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}_3\times V\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}_3\times V\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_6$, where $V$ is the Klein four-group, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. I came up with the following method, which seems to defeat the point of the problem:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}_3\times V&\simeq\mathbb{Z}_3\times(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2)\\
&\simeq\mathbb({Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2)\times\mathbb{Z}_2\\
&\simeq\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_2\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_6
\end{align*}

Is there a more constructive way to show this?

Comment: I'm not sure that defeats the point of the problem. I think it may exactly hit the point. More constructive, you can give an explicit isomorphism, but that isn't nearly as elegant.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response. I was looking to see if maybe there was a concise, explicit isomorphism.

Comment: These two forms represent two canonical decompositions of finite abelian groups - into subgroups belonging to each prime - a subgroup of order $3$ and one of order $4$; or as a direct product of cyclic groups with the order of each factor being an integer multiple of the orders of all smaller factors - so $2|6$. Understanding the relationship between these is important in understanding abelian groups. Here the second form tells us that the maximum order of an element is $6$, and the key to establishing it is to identify an element of order $6$, which is what you have done abstractly.